# minted: Force comments to be displayed in a more console-like font

Tags: fonts, minted

In [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted)'s default style, as well as a few others (emacs for instance), comments and other stuff like C preprocessor commands show up in a very un-code-like italic font, as shown in the 2 examples below.

I'm using this environment:

```
\newminted[cpp]{cpp}{frame=lines,framesep=2mm}
```

How could I change the font to a more console-like one? I tried playing with the `fontfamily` or `fontseries` minted options, but I didn't seem to get anywhere with that (I don't know what values to give to them aside from the ones that [`minted.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) states they support, and even those seem to either not do anything or break the code completely).

My configuration is Mac OS X Lion, using Latexian as editor, and latest TexLive from MacPorts - versions shown below.

```
texlive-latex @23089_0+doc
texlive-bin @2011_3+motif+x11
```

[image: weird font in comments and preprocessor commands]

[image: weird font in comments]

Comment: You should try `fontfamily=tt,fontshape=\upshape` for upright typewriter font.

Comment: I tried changing my minted definition to `\newminted[cpp]{cpp}{fontfamily=tt,fontshape=\upshape,frame=lines,framesep=2mm}`, but when compiling this in Latexian, `pdftex` hangs on 100% cpu while waiting for the .pyg output. If I remove `fontshape=\upshape`, it doesn't hang but it looks the same.

Comment: Could you include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with some code that you want to change the formatting of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. the font *is* “console-like” (that is, monospaced); it just happens to be *also* italic – which, by the way, is a completely valid formatting style and not that unusual (I usually use such a styling).
2. The italic formatting for comments is supplied by the Pygments style sheet, which supersedes the general font setting (since it’s more specific). In order to change it, you [need to create and register an own stylesheet](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I agree it is indeed monospaced, but personally I find it so much harder to read, probably because of the curliness of that specific font than the italics themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set the `minted` style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867762/change-highlight-colors-in-minted). For instance add:

```
\usemintedstyle{perldoc}
```

just after `\usepackage{minted}`
For a list of styles, try [this link](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)

or run

```
pygmentize -L styles
```